# Dismiss a Dialog after spinner item is selected

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am putting a `spinner` inside a `AlertDialog`. I want when user selects an item from spinner the dialog should close after this. But in my case when dialog displays it closes immediately by itself.

**Here is my code:**

```
final String gender[] = { "Male", "Female" };
            final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                    gender);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {


    tvGender.setText(gender[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setView(spinner)
                        .setTitle("Gender")
                        .create();
                dialog.show();
```

I hope I make sense.

Comment: what is the need of keeping spinner in alertDialog?

Comment: i want to show user some option from which he can select. am i doing wrong? if so then suggest me something else

Comment: spinner itself shows in alertDialog theme no need to add spinner in alertDailog.

Comment: user first have to click on the spinner them options will be shown. i want to show spinner to user so that he can click on it

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a while ago, and it was because onItemSelected was called when the spinner was initialized (I was setting an initial selected position). Try to use a boolean to avoid the first execution of onItemSelected.

```
private boolean firstExecution = true;

...

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(firstExecution){
                firstExecution = false;
                return;
            }

            tvGender.setText(gender[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Let me know if this solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
int i = 0;

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

    if(i == 1){
       tv_security_que.setText(gender[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
       dialog.dismiss();
    }
    i = 1;
}
```

it is helpful for you just add one variable and condition.